Airflow webserver pod unable to get log from worker pod
I have deployed Airflow [2.9.3] in AKS. But when executing the DAGS getting below error. Don't getting any clue what needs to be updated. I am using Helm [1.15.0] for deployment. I am totally clueless please help..
Error
Could not read served logs: HTTPConnectionPool(host='file-sensor-waiting-for-trigger-file-in-nprd-vgcdjyz8', port=8793): Max retries exceeded with url: /log/dag_id=file_sensor/run_id=manual__2024-11-06T03:10:17.703058+00:00/task_id=waiting_for_trigger_file_in_nprd/attempt=4.log (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f8f23131760>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known'))
Updated after doing some updates as below
I have created one "Connection" for "Azure Blob Storage" from Webportal with the name "adlsgen2". The connection was successfully tested.

Then I updated "logging:" in values.yaml with below code
config:
  core:
    dags_folder: '{{ include "airflow_dags" . }}'
    # This is ignored when used with the official Docker image
    load_examples: 'False'
    executor: '{{ .Values.executor }}'
    # For Airflow 1.10, backward compatibility; moved to [logging] in 2.0
    colored_console_log: 'False'
    remote_logging: '{{- ternary "True" "False" .Values.elasticsearch.enabled }}'
  logging:
    # remote_logging: '{{- ternary "True" "False" .Values.elasticsearch.enabled }}'
    remote_logging: 'True'
    remote_log_con_id: 'adlsgen2'
    remote_base_log_folder: 'wasb://airflowlogs@testadlsgen.blob.core.windows.net/logs'
    delete_local_logs: 'True'
    colored_console_log: 'False'

Then I executed below commands to roll out the DNS.

Then I executed below commands to re deploy the airflow with helm. And it was successfully deployed.
helm upgrade airflow apache-airflow/airflow --namespace dfs-test -f values.yaml

But I am getting below warning when looking into web server

When I am trying to access the web server from browser I am able to login and found that log massage is gone. But no log is showing. Also no log is written in Blob storage, where I made my webconnection for logging. .


are you using any airflow values file to configure Airflow’s executor, ingress, and logging settings? if you want to enable direct log access between pods, setup a configuration file, to enable the webserver to fetch logs from the worker pod over a specific port.

Hi @Arko. thanks for your reply. No I am not using any separate configuration file. Only using Helm 1.15.0. I found that the webserver pod is not getting logs from worker pod. The DAGS are executing properly. But logs are not able to capture. Please help.. I have given below information in logging
remote_logging: True
remote_base_log_folder: wasb://<container_name>@<storage_account>.blob.core.windows.net/path/to/logs
remote_log_conn_id: my_wasb
Deployment is success. But in webserver health issue is there.

Hi @Arko.. I am using values.yaml for deployment through Helm. There is no ingress, as it is default one. The airflow is deployed in separate namespace with updated airflow repo. main problem is webserver not getting logs from worker. Though everything is running fine.

Can you update all these details in your question once? edit your question and update your entire setup and config yaml etc for my ease of understanding. Will help me understand the situation better.

Hi @Arko.. Sure... Let me do that right now..

Hi @Arko, please find the update post with all further findings..

Hi @Arko did you get a chance further to look into? Thanks

So the startup probe failed indicates that the webserver container is struggling to pass its health checks, modify the values config in the yaml, sharing updated values file, check once

Thanks @Arko... The start up prob we have resolved.. But the main problem is The airflow web server console(UI) is not able to capture the Task/worker pod logs.. I have given screen shot in the post (The last image). We are using KuberenetesExecuter

This error typically arises from misconfigured DNS within the cluster
deploy one airflow namespace to isolate the environment.
kubectl create namespace airflow
kubectl config set-context --current --namespace=airflow

add the repo for apache
helm repo add apache-airflow https://airflow.apache.org
helm repo update

Create a config file for exampleairflow-values.yaml to specify the configuration of Airflow components, including the executor type, ingress, and logging settings
executor: "CeleryExecutor"
airflowVersion: "2.9.3"

web:
  service:
    type: LoadBalancer
  defaultUser:
    enabled: true
    username: admin
    password: admin
  secretKeyRef: airflow-webserver-secret-key  

workers:
  replicas: 2

ingress:
  web:
    enabled: true
    ingressClassName: nginx  
    hosts:
      - name: "airflow.example.com"  
  flower:
    enabled: false

logging:
  remote_logging: true
  remote_log_conn_id: "logfile"
  worker_log_server_port: 8793
  remote_log_fetch_timeout: 60  
  remote_log_fetch_retries: 5   



Deploy Airflow using Helm with this customized configuration
helm install airflow apache-airflow/airflow --namespace airflow -f airflow-values.yaml


After deployment, verify the same

Sometimes, Core DNS may not correctly resolve DNS. Restart CoreDNS to ensure it's functioning properly.
kubectl rollout restart deployment coredns -n kube-system
kubectl get pods -n kube-system -l k8s-app=kube-dns


To validate that DNS resolution is working correctly, do a nslookup  within the Airflow pod
kubectl run -i --tty dnsutils --image=tutum/dnsutils --rm=true -- bash
nslookup airflow-worker.airflow.svc.cluster.local


As you can see the DNS resolution inside the cluster is working as expected. The airflow-worker.airflow.svc.cluster.local domain is correctly resolving to multiple IP addresses.
Update- In addition to above troubleshooting, kindly configure permissions correctly for the storage account and AKS.
create an aks cluster
az aks create \
    --resource-group arkorg \
    --name arkoAKSCluster \
    --node-count 2 \
    --enable-managed-identity \
    --generate-ssh-keys \
    --location eastus


Create storage A/C
az storage account create \
    --name arkoairflowstorage \
    --resource-group arkorg \
    --location eastus \
    --sku Standard_LRS

Create blob storage container for logs
az storage container create \
    --account-name arkoairflowstorage \
    --name airflowlogs


Retrieve storage account key
az storage account keys list \
    --resource-group arkorg \
    --account-name arkoairflowstorage \
    --query "[0].value" -o tsv


Here is the updated values file
executor: "CeleryExecutor"
airflowVersion: "2.9.3"

web:
  service:
    type: LoadBalancer
  defaultUser:
    enabled: true
    username: admin
    password: admin
  env:
    - name: AIRFLOW__LOGGING__REMOTE_BASE_LOG_FOLDER
      value: "wasb://airflowlogs@arkoairflowstorage.blob.core.windows.net/logs"
    - name: AIRFLOW__LOGGING__REMOTE_LOG_CONN_ID
      value: "azure_blob_storage"

workers:
  replicas: 2
  env:
    - name: AIRFLOW__LOGGING__REMOTE_BASE_LOG_FOLDER
      value: "wasb://airflowlogs@arkoairflowstorage.blob.core.windows.net/logs"
    - name: AIRFLOW__LOGGING__REMOTE_LOG_CONN_ID
      value: "azure_blob_storage"

scheduler:
  env:
    - name: AIRFLOW__LOGGING__REMOTE_BASE_LOG_FOLDER
      value: "wasb://airflowlogs@arkoairflowstorage.blob.core.windows.net/logs"
    - name: AIRFLOW__LOGGING__REMOTE_LOG_CONN_ID
      value: "azure_blob_storage"

logging:
  remote_logging: true
  remote_log_conn_id: "azure_blob_storage"
  worker_log_server_port: 8793
  remote_log_fetch_timeout: 60
  remote_log_fetch_retries: 5

connections:
  - id: "azure_blob_storage"
    type: "wasb"
    extra: |
      {
        "connection_string": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=arkoairflowstorage;AccountKey=abcdefghijklmnopthisisasamplefakestringuseyourownoriginaloneyougetfromabovecommand==;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net"
      }

Few modifications I made such as the CeleryExecutor should be specified as executor in the main values.yaml , outside the config section.  Plus, I have added a web section which defines the service type, creds, and environment variables for remote logging.
Add the Airflow Helm Repository
helm repo add apache-airflow https://airflow.apache.org
helm repo update

Deploy Airflow to AKS
helm install airflow apache-airflow/airflow \
    --namespace airflow \
    --create-namespace \
    -f airflow-values.yaml


Verify Deployment
kubectl get pods -n airflow


from Airflow UI, confirm the connection under Admin > Connections and confirm Logging in Blob Storage by running a sample DAG to generate logs.

